# node v8.2.0 (64-bit) is not installed

Tags: javascript, hyper

> In hyper    (c:\users\dell\desktop\app> nvm use 8.2)  output:-node v8.2.0 (64-bit) is not installed.

But I have already installed node v8.2.0.

Comment: Could you please show the output of the following command: `nvm ls`

Comment: 10.15.1 is its output

Comment: If that is the only output, then it appears that node 8.2 is not installed.

Comment: Please run the following commands:
`nvm install 8.2`
`nvm use 8.2`

Comment: yayyyy it worked. thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

It happens when you install some node versions manually, try to delete them and install via nvm

```
nvm install 16.6.0

nvm use 16.6.0
```